# Can we hide the Sync on all the current sites and future sites using UI or using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, administration, pnp-powershell

I know that we can hide the Sync button for a document library or for all the document libraries inside a site as mentioned in this link https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/08/disable-sync-button-in-sharepoint-online.html

[image]

but my question is if there is a way to remove this globally on all the current sites and all future site?

Comment: There are blog posts with full Powershell scripts to disable sync for all sites in a site collection. Loop through all sites in the tenant.

Comment: @teylyn yes i can loop and set this for each site,, but this will not disable it on future sites unless i run the script again and again, that why i am asking if i can set this globally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Set-PnPTenant` in PnP PowerShell for disabling sync option for all lists and all sites in the SharePoint tenant:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com" -Interactive
Set-PnPTenant -DisableListSync $true
```

---

**OR** Try using `Set-SPOTenant` in SharePoint Online PowerShell:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com
Set-SPOTenant -HideSyncButtonOnTeamSite $true
```

**Reference**: [Sync in SharePoint and OneDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-sync)

Comment: did you try this command

Set-PnPTenant -DisableListSync $true

as i will get this error

 

Set-PnPTenant: Field or property "DisableListSync" does not exist.

Comment: also the second script will return this error `Set-SPOTenant: The term 'Set-SPOTenant' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Comment: For using `Set-SPOTenant`, you have to run it from SharePoint Online Management Shell. Install the SharePoint Online Management Shell and run the commands from it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online